# Is it safe to compile with an older version of Google Play Services?

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play-services

I like to stay as current as possible with libraries, but on a project I started a year ago I was on Eclipse and was using Google Play Service for Froyo. I recently started using Android Studio and of course now have a lot of broken code because I was initially using the most recent version of Google Play Services.

To fix it I basically imported the old Google Play Service for Froyo Eclipse project and made it a module in Android Studio that I referenced. I do not necessarily need the new features of the libarary and it is working. Here is my question: Is it safe to do this? I don't want this to bite me on newer devices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All newer versions of Google Play services (the app) are backward compatible with all previous versions of the SDK, meaning code compiled with an older SDK will continue to work even as Google Play services gets updated on every device.

Note that 'Google Play Services for Froyo' is in fact just the last version of Google Play services that supports Froyo - `3.2.65` (it was [Google Play services 4.0](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2013/10/google-play-services-40.html) which dropped support of Froyo). If you are using Gradle, you can still reference that in your `build.gradle` file without the need to import it as a module:

```
dependencies {
  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:3.2.65'
```

}

You can see the full list of Google Play services versions available via Gradle by looking in the `{android-sdk}/extras/google/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services` directory, which currently lists the following versions: `3.1.36`, `3.1.59`, `3.2.25`, `3.2.65`, `4.0.30`, `4.1.32`, `4.2.42`, `4.3.23`, `4.4.52`, `5.0.89`, `6.1.11`, `6.1.71`, `6.5.87`, and `7.0.0`.

You should **strongly** consider stepping through each version fixing issues as they come up as each release has a considerable number of fixes. In particular, [Google Play services 6.5](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2014/11/google-play-services-65.html) offers the ability to [selectively include APIs](https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html#split) so your application only includes the APIs you actually use.

Comment: I will have to try putting the version in my build.gradle file. Sorry, I'm new to Gradle and Android Studio and didn't know I could do that.

Comment: No problem! Eclipse never really made it clear that there were different versions of Google Play services - it was just the latest that supported Froyo and the very latest version. Gradle gives you the ability to pick exactly the version you need and it'll work from then on (updating your SDK doesn't change your dependency) - giving you control on when you move to a newer version.

Comment: I have to say this is sadly not true. I updated "com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0" to "com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.4.0" and my emulator stopped supporting the app. Had to reverse that to ensure backward compatibility with the emulator, all real devices seemed to be fine, but they are subject to updates.

Comment: @HopefullyHelpful - you're talking about updating your dependency. That's a completely separate topic from this question, which is specifically about *not* updating your dependency

Comment: @ianhanniballake Does this mean that if I update my app to compile using play services 9.4.0 all devices have to have the same version installed for the app to run?

Comment: @FilipeEsperandio - it means they need 9.4.0 or higher.